# Incremented seconds not printing

Tags: go

Am learning Google Go (very interesting, by the way) and the first program I used to learn was Matt Aimonetti's blog post:

[Real life concurrency in Go](http://matt.aimonetti.net/posts/2012/11/27/real-life-concurrency-in-go/)

```
package main 

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

var urls = [] string  {
    "http://golang.org",
    "http://www.espn.com",
    "http://www.google.com",
}

type HttpResponse struct {
    url       string
    response  *http.Response
    err       error
}

func asyncHttpGets(urls [] string) [] *HttpResponse {
    ch := make(chan *HttpResponse)
    responses := [] *HttpResponse{}
    seconds := 0
    for _, url := range urls {
        go func(url string) {
            fmt.Printf("Fetching %s \n", url)
            resp, err := http.Get(url)
            ch <- &HttpResponse{url, resp, err}
        }(url)
    }

    for {
        select {
        case r := <-ch:
            fmt.Printf("%s was fetched\n", r.url)
            responses = append(responses, r)
            if len(responses) == len(urls) {
                return responses
            }
        case <- time.After(50 * time.Millisecond):
            seconds++
            fmt.Printf(".")
            fmt.Sprintf("%v", seconds)
        }
    }
    return responses
}

func main() {
    results := asyncHttpGets(urls)
    for _, result := range results {
        fmt.Printf("%s status: %s\n", result.url, result.response.Status)
    }
}
```

I wanted to see the milliseconds also printed in the output so I create a seconds variable inside the asyncHttpGets method and incremented it in the same place that prints the "."

However, it never displays when I run:

```
 go build concurrency_example.go && ./concurrency_example
```

Outputs:

```
Fetching http://golang.org 
Fetching http://www.espn.com 
Fetching http://www.google.com 
...http://www.google.com was fetched
..http://golang.org was fetched
.........http://www.espn.com was fetched
http://www.google.com status: 200 OK
http://golang.org status: 200 OK
http://www.espn.com status: 200 OK
```

Question(s):

Why isn't the seconds counter being printed?

How do I print it by converting milliseconds to seconds (as int) and then convert to string?

This example and the explanations in the blog post was a great learning experience!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others mentioned the issue is that you used [fmt.Sprintf](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf) which formats a string according to a format (the first argument  of the function call).

Replace `fmt.Sprintf("%v", seconds)` by `fmt.Printf("%v\n", seconds)` to print the incremental value or `fmt.Printf("%v\n", seconds/1000)` if you want to print milliseconds. That said a better/more accurate way to get the elapsed time between the start of the function and when the time prints the time would be to use the `time` package as shown below:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "net/http"
  "time"
)

var urls = []string{
  "http://golang.org",
  "http://www.espn.com",
  "http://www.google.com",
}

type HttpResponse struct {
  url      string
  response *http.Response
  err      error
}

func asyncHttpGets(urls []string) []*HttpResponse {
  ch := make(chan *HttpResponse)
  responses := []*HttpResponse{}
  for _, url := range urls {
    go func(url string) {
      fmt.Printf("Fetching %s \n", url)
      resp, err := http.Get(url)
      ch <- &HttpResponse{url, resp, err}
    }(url)
  }
  start := time.Now()

  for {
    select {
    case r := <-ch:
      fmt.Printf("%s was fetched\n", r.url)
      responses = append(responses, r)
      if len(responses) == len(urls) {
        return responses
      }
    case t := <-time.After(50 * time.Millisecond):
      fmt.Println(t.Sub(start))
    }
  }
  return responses
}

func main() {
  results := asyncHttpGets(urls)
  for _, result := range results {
    fmt.Printf("%s status: %s\n", result.url, result.response.Status)
  }
}
```

We are collecting the timer output returned by `time.After` and subtracting the start time we set when the function is called. We end up with a [`time.Duration`](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration) value which we can print many different ways.

Answer (score 3):

Q: Why isn't the seconds counter being printed?

A: Because you used fmt.Sprintf, which returns a formatted string; it doesn't print that string. Use fmt.Printf.

Q: How do I print it by converting milliseconds to seconds (as int) and then convert to string?

A: If you have a value in milliseconds, simply divide by 1000 to get seconds. fmt.Printf will convert it to a string for you.

Answer (score 3):

1. You're using [`fmt.Sprintf`](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf), it returns a string, doesn't actually print it, you want to use [`fmt.Printf`](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Printf)
2. Simply `fmt.Println(ms/1000)` will print the seconds.

Comment: When trying fmt.Printf(seconds/1000), I got the following error: cannot use seconds / 1000 (type int) as type string in function argument. That's the original reason I found Sprintf after I googled this error. Also, the author didn't assign the time to anything, how can I assign it to something (in order to eliminate the seconds integer altogether)?

Comment: If you want `printf` then use : `fmt.Printf("%d\n", seconds / 1000)`, check the link in my answer.